# Powershell Domain join to specific domain controller

Tags: powershell, active-directory, wmi

Having some trouble joining some Windows XP clients to domain with a specific domain controller.
I need them to join a specific domain controller because of the many replication hops.
My code looks like this

```
$computer="."

$cred = Get-Credential -Credential Administrator

$domcred = Get-Credential
$domain = $domcred.GetNetworkCredential().Domain
$user = $domcred.UserName
$password = $domcred.GetNetworkCredential().Password

$comp = Get-WmiObject Win32_ComputerSystem -ComputerName $computer -Credential $cred -Authentication 6
$ret = $comp.JoinDomainOrWorkgroup($domain, $password, $user, $null, 3)
```

Maybe there is another alternative then WMI?
Add-Computer does not work in PS 2.0 with the Server parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I can't give you a full answer for windows XP here, as I don't have any XP systems to test on. It seems easier on more recent versions as you already pointed out. Google did however help me to find another system call wich might help.

It seems the `NetJoinDomain` command is available since Windows 2000. You can find the offical page [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb720851.aspx)

No examples in PowerShell on how to use it though. You can find an example for C# on [pinvoke](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/netapi32/NetJoinDomain.html). It might give you some hints on how to get things started in PowerShell.